# Bootstrap DateTimePicker - how to set width

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, pug

Jade:

```
td
  #cpf2.input-group.date
    input(type="text",value=(event.EDATE),style="width:200px")
    span.input-group-addon
      span.fa.fa-calender(aria-hidden="true")
  script(type="text/javascript")
    $(function () {
      $('#cpf2').datetimepicker({
        format: "DD-MM-YYYYY HH:mm",
        icons: {
          time: "fa fa-clock-o",
          date: "fa fa-calendar",
          up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
          down: "fa fa-arrow-down",
          previous: "fa fa-chevron-left",
          next: "fa fa-chevron-right"
        }
      });
    });
```

Output (on Chrome):

As you can see in the image, the formatting of the datetimepicker element is messed-up, with a large gap between the date-input and the calender-span.

Can anyone tell me how to resolve and be able to adjust the width of the entire datetimepicker element.

[image: datetimepicker poor styling]

Answer (score 0):

try to

```
padding-right = 0 px;
```

or

```
margin-right = 0px;
```

Do you use BootStrap?
You have to adjust the Grid system?

```
style="width:200px height:300px;"
```